# Display the Element ID

Tags: jquery

I am using this statement `alert(el.parent().next());`

But I am getting [object] [object] as an alert. How do I display the ID of the element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
alert(el.parent().next().attr("id"));
```

Comment: Maybe the id is empty or el.parent().next() doesn't match anything

Answer (score 0):

You must get its id attribute:

```
alert(el.parent().next().attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
el.parent().next().attr("id")
```